# POST request using npm request

Tags: node.js, curl, http-post

how can i do the following using npm request module?

```
curl -vvvvv -X POST -d "test msg" 'https://app.sms.sender/?destination=12341234' --cacert /loc/to/cert
```

I tried doing this:

```
 let options = {
    url: format(process.env.PATH_URL, number),
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': process.env.USER_AGENT,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    agentOptions: {
        cert: fs.readFileSync(process.env.SMS_CERT_PATH),
    },
    body: "test msg"
};

//store url in env
request.post(options, function(error, response, body) {
    ...
});
```

---

But i kept receiving `cannot read property 'toString' of undefined`.
On top of it, when I print out the option on the console, 
I get the following. Is this suppose to be correct?

```
...
agentOptions : {
    cert: <Buffer 2d 2d 45 46 76 ... ... ... >
}
...
```

Comment: try to log the error in your request.post and give us the result

Comment: i did but that error message `cannot read property 'toString' of undefined` did not comes from the response error. I am suspecting it could missing from the option or something

Comment: Where did you put the `toString`? And is the query part in the env var?

Comment: @NorTicUs there is no toString() method used in my codes

Comment: Good to know! That could be related to the fact that your using `x-www-form-urlencoded` header but no `form` in the option object (maybe `request` in trying to stringify it since it detected the header). Could you try to match the documentation example ? https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-url-encoded-forms

Comment: @NorTicUs. I get what you trying to say i was trying to match my curl command as it is working. I am refering to this, under the -d command `https://www.computerhope.com/unix/curl.htm`

Comment: What I'm suggesting is to use de `form`  key instead of your URL formatting

Comment: @NorTicUs like this ? `form: {"body": msg}`

Comment: More like `options = {..., form: {destination: '123456'}}`. Since it's form-urlencoded you can have a body too (not sure it's good practice)